# Determining 'type' of spring-mass model.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Good day! I am working on an ODE problem in which I need to classify why type of spring-mass model the problem has described.

> Consider a pendulum of length $L$ that swings back and forth without friction. Let $\theta(t)$ be the angle that the pendulum makes with a vertical line. We derive the ODE
>
> $$\theta''(t)+\frac{g}{L}\theta(t)=0.$$
>
> The function $\theta(t)$ approximately satisfies this, at least if the angle $\theta(t)$ remains relatively close to zero (say, $|\theta(t)| \leq \frac{\pi}{6}$, about $30$ degrees). Which of the spring-mass models does this correspond to - overdamped, critically damped, underdamped,or undamped?

Originally, I thought this model was undamped as the problem states that there is no friction present in the pendulum. Additionally, my thought is that if $\theta(t)$ should be "relatively close" to $0$, then, after finding the characteristic equation, we would want $c=0$. I am being tripped up by the wording of "$\theta(t)$ remains relatively close to zero." Any hints or tips to navigate this wording and answer the question would be appreciated.

Comment: Clearly there is no damping since you have no $\theta'(t)$ term in the ode. Only stiffness is present due to the spring. Stiffness goes with $\theta(t)$ and damping goes with $\theta'(t)$.

Comment: Oh dear, I completely misread this... I was processing the $\theta(t)$ as the $\theta'(t)$. Thank you @Nasser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight, I realized that I misread my own question. Since there is no $\theta'(t)$ in the ODE, we have $c=0$, thus making this ODE undamped. The general solution is, therefore, $\theta(t)=c_{1}\cos(\omega t)+c_{2}\sin(\omega t)$.